# Parallelizing nested for loops using foreach

Tags: r, foreach, nested-loops, doparallel

I am trying to parallelize my nested for loops. While my code is long and a bit complicated, here is the general idea:

```
for (i in 1:n){
   simulate y
   for (j in 1:m){
      some computation based on y
   }
   use the results from the above loop to do some more computation
}
```

I was able to parallelize the inner loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:n){
   simulate y
   x=foreach (j in 1:m, combine="cbind") %dopar% {
      some computation based on y
   }
   use x to do some more computation
}
```

But I am not sure how to parallelize the outer loop as well. I tried the following:

```
foreach (i in 1:n, .combine="cbind") %:% {
   simulate y
   x=foreach (j in 1:m, .combine="cbind") %dopar% {
      some computation based on y
   }
   use x to do some more computation
}
```

But this doesn't work. It gives me the following error:
Error in foreach(i = 1:n, .combine = "cbind") %:% { :
no function to return from, jumping to top level

Please help.

Comment: Use `%do%`, not `%:%`. Run `vignette("nested", package = "foreach")` at a command prompt.

Comment: When you parallelize the outer loop, most of the cores will be in use, so where are the parallelized operations from the the inner loop going to run? Parallelizing a parallelized loop will unlike provide a significant improvement unless you have lots and lots of cores.  I would focus on optimizing the inner loop first.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I did try %do% instead of %:%  and it did work. Not sure if it made things any faster. Would you explain the difference between them?

Comment: @Dave2e explained it in simple terms. As for making things faster, that's the point in parallelizing. Can't you time the code with `system.time`? Or with `?Rprof` and `?summaryRprof`.